# Mixin not working Vue.js - Error: {method} refrenced but not defined

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, mixins

I have a mixin in my Vue project. But, it's not working.
Here's the code:

**InvMixin.js**

```
export default {
    created() {
        console.log("hi");
    },

    methods: {
        helloa() {
            console.log('hi from mixin');
        },
        proal() {
            console.log("hoye");
        }
    }
}
```

**template**

```
import invMixin from "./InventoryMixin.js";
export default {

  mixins: [invMixin],

 methods: {
        check() {
            this.helloa();
        }
    }
}
```

**Output**

> *helloa* is referenced but not defined
>   Created of mixin not working

Can someone help to solve it, please? Thankyou!!

Comment: please share a bit more of template.vue, specifically between the import and the methods

Comment: which is the real name of the mixin ? `InventoryMixin` or `invMixin`, try using only one

Comment: Is path of InventoryMixin.js is correct ? Just asking to be clear.

Comment: This should work perfecly well except the code you posted isn't the same you're using. The only case I had that is simmilar to yours is when I accidently placed the `mixins:[]` inside of a prop which threw no errors.

Answer (score 2):

Just importing your mixin is not enough. Declare it in your component:

```
// In your component
import invMixin from "./InventoryMixin.js";

export default {
  name: "MyComponent",
  mixins: [invMixin] //declare mixin here
}
```

Comment: Done, still the same

Comment: @idk there are any differences between **imvMixin.js** and **InventoryMixin.js**? And schow the complete component where you are using the mixin